# Conditional Statement in React From Service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So what i'm trying to do is on a conditional, show the email line if the logged.get("firstName") and logged.get("lastName") values are empty. How do I write a  condition in react that would solve this?

```
return (
      <>
        {logged && (
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            color="secondary"
            className={classes.headline}
          >
            Welcome back{" "}
            <b>
              {logged.get("firstName")} {logged.get("lastName")}
            </b>
            <b> {logged.get("email")} </b>
          </Typography>
        )}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just use inline condition like below

```
{ 
   logged.get("firstName") == null 
         && logged.get("lastName") == null ?
   <b> {logged.get("email")} </b> : null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
      <>
        {logged && (
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            color="secondary"
            className={classes.headline}
          >
            Welcome back{" "}
            <b>
              {logged.get("firstName")} {logged.get("lastName")}
            </b>
            {
              (logged.get("firstName") == "" && logged.get("lastName") == "") &&
               <b>logged.get("email")</b>
             }
          </Typography>
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ (logged.get("firstName")).length > 0 && (logged.get("lastName")).length > 0 && <b> logged.get("email")} </b> }`

Answer (score 0):

```
{ logged.get("firstName") && logged.get("lastName")
  ? <b>
     {logged.get("firstName")} {logged.get("lastName")}
    </b>
  : <b> {logged.get("email")} </b>

}
```